# How can I put a div in center in every resolution? (with CSS and only horizontally)

Tags: html, css, center

`margin: 0 auto` doesn't work for some reason. I've tried `text-align` in the header, as well as many other things, but nothing is working.

My code:

```css
div.middle {
   font-family: "New Times Roman";
 background-color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.4);
 padding: 0;
 border: 2px solid rgb(75, 75, 75);
 border-radius: 8px;
 width: 85%;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
div#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="middle">
        <p> Text........ </p>
        <p> Text........ </p>
        <p> Text........ </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You misspelled, the `text-align: centre` should be `text-align:center` ... fix that and your code works. You can also remove `margin: 0 auto` as it doesn't work for inline elements.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `display: inline-block` to make the div act like a div again.

```css
div.middle {
   font-family: "New Times Roman";
 background-color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.4);
 padding: 0;
 border: 2px solid rgb(75, 75, 75);
 border-radius: 8px;
 width: 85%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="middle">
        <p> Text........ </p>
        <p> Text........ </p>
        <p> Text........ </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I see that it works here, but for some reason it doesn't work for me. Even if I remove the display: inline-block or the outer div.

Comment: You need to provide more information in your original question then

Comment: Yeah, put all of the relevant information and code in your original question :) I, and others, will check it out

Comment: I can't it always tell me that something is wrong with the code, etc. because linebreaks and stuff. So I just send the 1-2 weeks old public link: " www.starcraft2blog.co.nf " do you see something in it what doesn't let the div to be centered?

Comment: Yes, your `position: absolute` attribute. Please update your question instead of discussing details in a comment.

Comment: No, there isn't position absolute, at least in the new one, I would show my new html/css BUT IT DOESN'T LET ME (I have to go for now, I will be online tomorrow later.)